# occurred error while use zkcopy copy data from zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

1、using zkcopy and run cmd as following:
java -jar target/zkcopy.jar --source xxxx:2181/clickhouse --target xxxx:2181/clickhouse

2、cmd output as following:

```
2021-09-07 21:47:33,542 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy - using 10 concurrent workers to copy data
2021-09-07 21:47:33,542 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy - delete nodes = true
2021-09-07 21:47:33,542 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy - ignore ephemeral nodes = true
2021-09-07 21:47:33,543 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.reader.Reader - Reading /clickhouse from 10.201.226.32:2181
2021-09-07 21:47:34,590 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.reader.Reader - Processing, total=12417, processed=3142
2021-09-07 21:47:35,655 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.reader.Reader - Processing, total=12417, processed=6059
2021-09-07 21:47:36,655 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.reader.Reader - Processing, total=12417, processed=9172
2021-09-07 21:47:37,655 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.reader.Reader - Processing, total=12497, processed=12497
2021-09-07 21:47:37,657 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.reader.Reader - Completed.
2021-09-07 21:47:37,687 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer - Writing data...
2021-09-07 21:47:38,338 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer - Committing transaction
2021-09-07 21:47:38,954 [main] INFO com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer - Committing transaction
Exception in thread "main" picocli.CommandLine$ExecutionException: Error while calling command (com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy@7960847b): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:458)
at picocli.CommandLine.access$300(CommandLine.java:134)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:538)
at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:656)
at picocli.CommandLine.call(CommandLine.java:883)
at picocli.CommandLine.call(CommandLine.java:834)
at com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy.main(ZkCopy.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.AutoCommitTransactionWrapper.maybeCommitTransaction(AutoCommitTransactionWrapper.java:74)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.AutoCommitTransactionWrapper.create(AutoCommitTransactionWrapper.java:39)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.upsertNode(Writer.java:147)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.update(Writer.java:96)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.update(Writer.java:104)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.update(Writer.java:104)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.update(Writer.java:104)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.update(Writer.java:104)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.update(Writer.java:104)
at com.github.ksprojects.zkcopy.writer.Writer.write(Writer.java:65)
at com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy.call(ZkCopy.java:86)
at com.github.ksprojects.ZkCopy.call(ZkCopy.java:14)
at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:456)
```